Spring boot unable to find the test class
I am writing a test for a REST Controller which returns nothing but a String.
package com.sample.testing;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}

This is my test class for the above controller,
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class HelloControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
   public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}

This is what I get in console when I individually run test for the `HelloControllerTest class.
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.sample.testing.HelloControllerTest](--tests filter)
 `

My build gradle file,
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.9"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
    id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native") version "0.9.28"
    id("org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert") version "3.3.2"
}

group = "com.sample"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["snippetsDir"] = file("build/generated-snippets")

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-testcontainers")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.test {
    outputs.dir(project.extra["snippetsDir"]!!)
}

tasks.asciidoctor {
    inputs.dir(project.extra["snippetsDir"]!!)
    dependsOn(tasks.test)
}


Maybe import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test instead of org.junit.Test? This should be the standard for Spring Boot 3.2.

@oliver_t It worked what is the difference ?

org.junit.Test is from JUnit4 which is supported by Spring Boot 3+ but not recommended. org.junit.jupiter.api.Test is from JUnit5 which is preferrable

Depending on the TestRunner, old JUnit4 Tests will be ignored or included. Use the JUnit5 annotations to be on the safe side.
